# El sonido de la J de José, en la California española

Tags: méxico, historia, hispanoamérica, fonología

La jota que tiene el nombre *José* hoy lleva el sonido /χ/, pero muy antes representaba algo como /ʒ/ (le jazz) y también luego el /ʃ/ (a ship). ¿Cómo era en la etapa española de la Alta California, entre 1769 y 1821?  Los pobladores hispanos eran principalmente sonorenses, encabezados por unos vascos y catalanes. Por ser tan remoto el lugar, su lenguaje podía haber tardado en cambiar.

¿El [reajuste de las consonantes sibilantes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reajuste_de_las_sibilantes_del_idioma_espa%C3%B1ol) habrá llegado? (Wikipedia no menciona a México.) ¿Podía haberse dicho el nombre José con la fricativa postalveolar sonora, como la actual forma portuguesa, o sería ya sorda?

Quiero saber si un José de aquel lugar pudo firmar en ruso como Жосе o Хосе.

Comment: Como puedes comprobar, esta pregunta nos ha gustado mucho, pero creo que nos ha dejado un poco a todos de piedra por su complejidad. Según el enlace que has mandado, la transición al sonido actual de la "j" tuvo lugar durante el siglo XVII y no especifica regiones. Yo entiendo que en la segunda mitad del siglo XVIII ese cambio ya habría llegado a México. Pero claro, es solo una suposición. Por otro lado, tal vez deberías especificar cómo se pronuncia "Жосе" en ruso.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El español antiguo tenía seis sibilantes: dentales, apicoalveolares y postalveolares, en pares sorda/sonora. El español actual sólo tiene sibilantes sordas, y tiene dos variantes principales, una con tres puntos de articulación (el estándar peninsular con /θ/, /s/ y /x/), y otra con dos (el estándar americano con /s/ y /x/), dejando de lado las múltiples realizaciones fonéticas regionales. Esta última tiene como origen mayormente el habla de Andalucía, donde los cambios fonéticos del castellano (que avanzaba desde el norte) llegaron más tarde y de manera diferente.

En el español norteño (de Castilla) se perdió primero la distinción entre sordas y sonoras, y luego, a fines del siglo XVI, los tres fonemas resultantes se "apartaron" uno de otro: el dental se hizo netamente interdental y el postalveolar se hizo velar.

En Andalucía y América, en cambio, se perdió primero la distinción entre la posición dental y la apicoalveolar, durante el siglo XVI, y luego la distinción de sonoridad, a fines del mismo siglo. El fonema postalveolar pasó a ser velar/glotal un siglo más tarde.

Para el año 1800 el sistema fonológico ya debía ser aproximadamente como el actual. Con toda seguridad no había ya distinción entre sibilantes sordas y sonoras (realizadas ahora siempre como sordas). Quizá en algún dialecto arcaico de alguna región apartada todavía podía escucharse una postalveolar en vez de una velar, pero en mi opinión el tal José, en ruso, no habría usado la letra *zhe* (Ж), que de hecho representa una fricativa retrofleja sonora, para representar el sonido inicial de su nombre. En todo caso podría haber usado *sha* (Ш), que representa la retrofleja sorda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por los detalles. Veo que la fricatez se desvia demasiado del sonido original para usar esa Ж. La seña Шосе parece significar "camino" así que es difícil comprobar lo último.