# ¿Qué sonidos se han incluido o excluido del idioma castellano a lo largo de los siglos?

Tags: historia, pronunciación, letras

Estuve leyendo con detenimiento la respuesta de [Revisions of Spanish orthography / ¿Qué revisiones ha tenido la ortografía española?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10328/1674) y hay fragmentos del tipo:

> - **1741** [Orthographía española](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADnea_Massa-Senigallia)
>     (...)
>
>   - W called *walima* rejected as a letter, foreign words with it to be pronounced as *vv* as vowel-consonant (that is, *uv* /ub/)
>   - Began use of *x* for /ks/ <sub>(but rejected /gs/)</sub>
>   - Rejection of the spelling *ll* for /l/

Asimismo, en [Paso de B a U: ¿evolución fonética o falta de ortografía?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/25982/1674) se lee:

> había en latín una /b/ escrita "B", que con el correr del tiempo empezó a debilitarse entre (y generalmente luego de) vocales y a pronunciarse como fricativa [β]. Ésta fue la primera iteración de un proceso de lenición que después volvió a repetirse en romance (actuando sobre la /b/ producto de la lenición de /p/) al norte de la [línea La Spezia-Rímini](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADnea_Massa-Senigallia).

De [¿Podría un hispanohablante actual entenderse bien con uno del pasado?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17145/1674) leo:

> Existe, en realidad, un texto aún más antiguo al de las Glosas: los [Cartularios de Valpuesta](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartularios_de_Valpuesta), del siglo IX (...) El enlace explica algunos cambios, tanto gráficos y fonéticos (f > h, x > ç, u > o, etc.) como sintácticos (...).

El caso famoso de México / Méjico planteado en [El sonido de la J de José, en la California española](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21614/1674) nos deja una respuesta interesante en forma de:

> El español antiguo tenía seis sibilantes: dentales, apicoalveolares y postalveolares, en pares sorda/sonora. El español actual sólo tiene sibilantes sordas, y tiene dos variantes principales, una con tres puntos de articulación (el estándar peninsular con /θ/, /s/ y /x/), y otra con dos (el estándar americano con /s/ y /x/), dejando de lado las múltiples realizaciones fonéticas regionales. Esta última tiene como origen mayormente el habla de Andalucía, donde los cambios fonéticos del castellano (que avanzaba desde el norte) llegaron más tarde y de manera diferente.
>
> En el español norteño (de Castilla) se perdió primero la distinción entre sordas y sonoras, y luego, a fines del siglo XVI, los tres fonemas resultantes se "apartaron" uno de otro: el dental se hizo netamente interdental y el postalveolar se hizo velar.
>
> (...)
>
> Para el año 1800 el sistema fonológico ya debía ser aproximadamente como el actual.

Siguiendo con la *x*, en [Why is the "X" in 'México' or 'Texas' pronunced as the letter "J"? / ¿Por qué la "X" de palabras como "México" o "Texas" se pronuncian como "J"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/245/1674) se decía:

> In Old Spanish, words like "caja", "bajo", and "jarabe" were originally spelled with an "x", and pronounced as "sh" ([voiceless palato-alveolar sibilant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_palato-alveolar_sibilant)).

Para termina, en [¿Por qué hay c, k y q? ¿Es que alguna vez se pronunciaron distinto?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20168/1674) se comenta:

> La grafía *qu* sí representaba un sonido distinto, la oclusia labiovelar sorda /kʷ/ (que no es lo mismo que /kw/, que son dos fonemas seguidos). En la evolución del latín al español, nuestra lengua perdió la coarticulación labial (la ʷ, vaya) y por tanto se fusionó con la antigua /k/. El hecho de que sigamos distinguiendo las grafías *c* (y *k*) y *qu* no es más que mero *respeto a la etimología*.

Todo ello son referencias utilísimas, trozos muy importantes de información que intento *casar* con el artículo [Evolución fonética y fonológica del latín al castellano](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evoluci%C3%B3n_fon%C3%A9tica_y_fonol%C3%B3gica_del_lat%C3%ADn_al_castellano). En particular, me gustaría saber si ha habido inclusiones o exclusiones de sonidos en el idioma castellano a lo largo de los siglos. ¿Existe alguna lista más o menos exhaustiva?

Comment: Entiendo que la pronunciación de *caja* y *bajo* sería similar a sus equivalentes actuales en catalán/gallego: caixa (he notado que se omite la *i* en Barcelona) y baixo. ¿Me equivoco?

Comment: @PabloLozano en catalán se pronuncia la `/ix/` como la `/sh/` inglesa (_fresh_), por lo que a efectos mentales puede pensarse en _casha_ para decir _caixa_. Un poco como hablaba Cristiano Ronaldo el castellano, vaya, por lo que sí encajaría con la pronunciación gallega y portuguesa.

Answer (score 3):

No sé si es lo que buscas, pero en la Wikipedia se encuentran tablas con los fonemas que ha tenido el idioma español desde sus orígenes hasta la actualidad.

#### Español medieval

En el artículo sobre el [español medieval](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1ol_medieval), que ocupa el español desde el siglo IX hasta el XV, aparece la siguiente tabla para las consonantes:

```
                            Dento-
                   Labial  alveolar  Palatal  Velar
obstruyente sorda    p       t, tˢ     č       k
            sonora   b       d, dᶻ     ǰ       g
fricativa   sorda    ɸ       s         š
            sonora   β       z         ž
nasal                m       n         ñ
vibrante                     ɾ, r
lateral                      l         ʎ
```

Y la siguiente tabla para las vocales:

```
             Anterior  Central  Posterior
Cerrada         i                  u
Semicerrada     e                  o
Semiabierta     *ɛ                 *ɔ
Abierta                   a
```

Notas:

- El sistema fonológico de entonces era mucho más cercano al de las demás lenguas romances.
- No existía el sonido de la letra *c* ante *e, i* como el que usamos hoy, ni el sonido actual de la *j* (o *g* ante *e, i*).
- La *v* tenía un sonido fricativo, pero no se sabe si era bilabial o labiodental.
- Se estima que las vocales semiabiertas, que solo se daban en sílaba tónica, debieron de desaparecer rápidamente, dado lugar a diptongo crecientes y a vocales semicerradas.

#### Español medio o aúrico

Es el paso previo al español actual, y es el resultado de un proceso llamado [reajuste de las sibilantes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reajuste_de_las_sibilantes_del_idioma_espa%C3%B1ol), caracterizado por:

- Perder la oposición sonora/sorda, a favor de las sordas.
- La predorsodentoalveolar africada sorda /t͡s/ primero se fricativizó, resultando en una [s] predorsodental (como en la pronunciación actual de las variedades americanas y zonas andaluzas seseantes), luego en las variedades septentrionales se adelantó su punto de articulación hacia el sonido interdental fricativo sordo /θ/.
- La prepalatal (o postalveolar) fricativa sorda /ʃ/ pospuso su punto de articulación velarizándose /x/, dando el sonido moderno de la j y la g (ante e/i) actuales.

Así pues, en el [español medio o aúrico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1ol_medio) la tabla de las consonantes queda así:

```
                   Labial       Alveolar    Palatal  Velar  Glotal
                           Predorsal Apical
obstruyente sorda    p             t           tʃ      k
            sonora   b             d                   g
fricativa   sorda    f        s̪̺         s̺      ʃ             (h)
nasal                m             n           ɲ
vibrante                          ɾ, r
aproximante lateral                l           ʎ
            no lat.                            ʝ
```

Las vocales en esta etapa del idioma eran ya las mismas que las actuales.

Notas:

- El sonido [h] era ya marginal en el siglo XVII probablemente, aunque a día de hoy aún persiste en variantes andaluzas y extremeñas.
- En América, Canarias y casi toda Andalucía el fonema /s̺/ se fusionó con /s̪̺/.
- Numerosas variedades perdieron la distinción entre el fonema /ʎ/ y el fonema /ʝ/.

#### Español moderno

La tabla de consonantes para el [español moderno](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonolog%C3%ADa_del_espa%C3%B1ol) según sus rasgos fonológicos queda así:

```
                                      [+consonante]
                           [-dorsal]                 [+dorsal]
                   [+lab][-cor] [-lab][+cor] [+pal][-vel] [-pal][+vel]
[-son]                /B/ /p/      /D/ /t/       /č/         /G/ /k/
[-son][+cont]           /f/        /s/,/θ*/      /J/          /x/
[+son][+nas]            /m/          /n/         /ɲ/    
[+son][-nas][+lat]                   /l/        /ʎ*/    
[+son][-nas][-lat]                 /ɾ/ /r/
```

Donde las abreviaturas son referencias a esta lista:

- [± consonante]
- [± sonante]
- [± dorsal]
- [± labial]
- [± coronal]
- [± palatal]
- [± velar]
- [± continuante]
- [± nasal]
- [± lateral]

Comment: Fantástico compendio, ¡gracias Charlie! Tengo aún que familiarizarme con el sonido que representa cada nombre, pero para empezar resulta interesante lo de _Perder la oposición sonora/sorda, a favor de las sordas_.